# How to perform Boolean operations on multiple graphics in js-angusj-clipper

Tags: javascript, boolean-operations, clipper

I use js-angusj-clipper. I have three squares. Their positions are like this. I let them perform intersection operations, but I can’t get the correct results. My code is as follows:

```
    this._clipper = await loadNativeClipperLibInstanceAsync(
      NativeClipperLibRequestedFormat.WasmWithAsmJsFallback,
    );

    const group = [[[
            {
                "x": 141.88,
                "y": 177.22
            },
            {
                "x": 229.06,
                "y": 177.22
            },
            {
                "x": 229.06,
                "y": 60.62
            },
            {
                "x": 141.88,
                "y": 60.62
            }
        ],[
            {
                "x": 113.12,
                "y": 196.81
            },
            {
                "x": 190.58,
                "y": 196.81
            },
            {
                "x": 190.58,
                "y": 123.12
            },
            {
                "x": 113.12,
                "y": 123.12
            }
        ],[
            {
                "x": 164.55,
                "y": 210.16
            },
            {
                "x": 269.98,
                "y": 210.16
            },
            {
                "x": 269.98,
                "y": 140.15
            },
            {
                "x": 164.55,
                "y": 140.15
            }
        ]]];

    const subjectInputs = [];
    const clipInputs = [];
    group.forEach((pointsList, index) => {
      pointsList.forEach((points) => {
        if (index !== group.length - 1) {
          subjectInputs.push({ data: points, closed: true });
        } else {
          clipInputs.push({ data: points });
        }
      });
    });

    let polyResult =
        this._clipper.clipToPaths({
          clipType: 'intersect',
          subjectInputs,
          clipInputs,
          subjectFillType: PolyFillType.EvenOdd,
          clipFillType: PolyFillType.EvenOdd,
        }) || [];
```

The positions of the three rectangles are as follows:

[image]

But the result is wrong:

[image]

The correct result should be only one middle rectangle:

[image]

What should i do? thank you!

Comment: Please always try to use a language tag. This way you'll attract relevant and repel irrelevant ones.